# Unity Hololens 2 Development

Tags: unity-game-engine, navigation, hololens, windows-mixed-reality

I want to make an indoor navigation app with HoloLens 2 device in Unity. But I don't have any experience with HoloLens. I have searched that azure spatial cloud will help but I want to use QR to localise in the Scene not azure. I have build the same app on Android and iOS with AR-Foundation Unity (ARCORE AND ARKIT) and its working fine. I want to make the same app for HoloLens.

Answer (score 0):

Microsoft does provide QR code recognition. Samples for QR code on HoloLens2 are at [QR code tracking](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/mixed-reality/qr-code-tracking#getting-the-coordinate-system-for-a-qr-code). AF Foundation does not support HoloLens2. Please refer to the [Platform Support](https://docs.unity3d.com/Packages/com.unity.xr.arfoundation@5.0/manual/index.html) for AF Foundation.